# how to get COUNT of a column against a set of specific values of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

```
+------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| R_ID |   BU  |  DIV  | Product | C_Func  |
+------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1   |  BU1  | Div1  |   P1    |  Dev    |
|  2   |  BU2  | Div2  |   P2    |  Dev    |
|  3   |  BU2  | Div2  |   P2    |  BA     |
|  4   |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  Dev    |
|  5   |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  QA     |
|  6   |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  Dev    |
|  7   |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  QA     |
|  8   |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  BA     |
|  9   |  BU1  | Div1  |   P1    |  Dev    |
|  10  |  BU2  | Div2  |   P2    |  Dev    |
|  11  |  BU2  | Div2  |   P2    |  BA     |
|  12  |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  Dev    |
|  13  |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  QA     |
|  14  |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  Dev    |
|  15  |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  QA     |
|  16  |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  BA     |
|  17  |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  QA     |
|  18  |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  Dev    |
|  19  |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  QA     |
|  20  |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  BA     |
+------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
```

I have data in a table as shown above which i fetched using sql joins and all.
what I want is the number of count of 'R_ID' working on set of (BU,DIV,Product,C_func).
for e.g.
I want to know how many 'R_ID' are there for (BU1,Div1,P1,Dev) for that the count should be 2 as there are 2 entries for the set (BU1,Div1,P1,Dev).

Expected output:

```
 +-------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
 |   BU  |  DIV  | Product | C_Func  | Count |
 +-------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
 |  BU1  | Div1  |   P1    |  Dev    |   2   |
 |  BU2  | Div2  |   P2    |  Dev    |   2   |
 |  BU2  | Div2  |   P2    |  BA     |   2   |
 |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  Dev    |   2   |
 |  BU3  | Div3  |   P3    |  QA     |   3   |
 |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  Dev    |   3   |
 |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  QA     |   3   |
 |  BU4  | Div4  |   P4    |  BA     |   3   |       
 +-------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
select   BU, DIV, Product, C_Func, count(*)
from     mytable
group by BU, DIV, Product, C_Func
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt thought it would be this simple

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `GROUP BY` scenario.

```
SELECT BU,DIV,Product,C_Func,COUNT(R_ID)
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY BU,DIV,Product,C_Func
```

You need to `group by` all those columns which you want to see them as groups and apply `count` on the left out column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BU,DIV,Product,C_Func,COUNT(*)
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY BU,DIV,Product,C_Func
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternative approaches, depending on the uniqueness of `R_ID`. If it is defined as a **UNIQUE INDEX**, then you can simply count the rows as:

```
SELECT BU1 , COUNT(*)
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY BU1   ;
```

If it is **not** define as a **UNIQUE INDEX** and you want to know how many different indices are, the query then becomes:

```
SELECT BU1 , COUNT(DISTINCT R_ID)
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY BU1   ;
```

The same type of query can be used for the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
select   BU, DIV, Product, C_Func, count(1)
from     table
group by BU, DIV, Product, C_Func
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH tb(R_ID,BU,DIV,Product,C_Func)AS(
    SELECT 1,'BU1','Div1','P1','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'BU2','Div2','P2','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'BU2','Div2','P2','BA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'BU3','Div3','P3','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'BU3','Div3','P3','QA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'BU4','Div4','P4','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,'BU4','Div4','P4','QA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,'BU4','Div4','P4','BA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,'BU1','Div1','P1','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,'BU2','Div2','P2','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11,'BU2','Div2','P2','BA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12,'BU3','Div3','P3','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 13,'BU3','Div3','P3','QA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 14,'BU4','Div4','P4','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 15,'BU4','Div4','P4','QA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 16,'BU4','Div4','P4','BA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 17,'BU3','Div3','P3','QA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 18,'BU4','Div4','P4','Dev' UNION ALL
    SELECT 19,'BU4','Div4','P4','QA' UNION ALL
    SELECT 20,'BU4','Div4','P4','BA'
    )
    SELECT BU,DIV,Product,C_Func,COUNT(DISTINCT R_ID) AS [R_ID_Count] 
    FROM tb GROUP BY BU,DIV,Product,C_Func
```

```
BU   DIV  Product C_Func R_ID_Count
---- ---- ------- ------ -----------
BU1  Div1 P1      Dev    2
BU2  Div2 P2      BA     2
BU2  Div2 P2      Dev    2
BU3  Div3 P3      Dev    2
BU3  Div3 P3      QA     3
BU4  Div4 P4      BA     3
BU4  Div4 P4      Dev    3
BU4  Div4 P4      QA     3
```